# Change style on ASP DropDownlist

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

Is it possible to change the graphics for the arrow down on the dropdownlist control, without having to create a custom control? I need all the normal properties, just want to style the arrow down a bit.

Comment: http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2013/12/aspnet-dropdownlist-change-arrow-image.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily use custom graphics for any form element by using javascript and CSS, please see for examples:

http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

http://www.noupe.com/css/form-elements-40-cssjs-styling-and-functionality-techniques.html

http://www.noupe.com/css/47-excellent-ajax-css-forms.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use third party controls, but if you are looking to change the look of your standard tools that would not be very possible, since those are derived from the standard controls of the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

There a [third party controls](http://easylistbox.com/demoCombo.aspx?rl=fp) that can help you do that.

Comment: seems the page is no longer there